# Find a subspace in R^2 that have the next vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the next excersise about subspaces:
Find the subspace in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that have the next vectors:
 $$v_1 = (1,3)$$
 $$v_2 = (-1,2)$$
My idea was to do a linear combination and try to find the conditions of the subspace. Is it correct what I was doing? Is there another way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

What is the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbf R^2$?

Answer (score 0):

I mean...., they are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $dim(\mathbb{R}^2) = 2$..